# Correct URL in Domain Driven Development

Tags: java, rest, domain-driven-design

Suppose a completely theoretical path.
I've alway wondered what would be the correct URL, from a REST-ful point of view?

```
 /users/{userId}/details
```

OR

```
/users/details/{userId}
```

I highly incline on the first one, but just to make sure...

Comment: Check this out: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/restful-java-with/9780596809300/ch01s02.html

BTW 1st variant makes much more sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/users/{userId}/details` makes more sense.

You can refer as some famous API ([Spotify for example](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/artists/))